# VB NET check SQL server image data type for null or empty

Tags: sql-server-2012, vb.net-2010

I need to check for null value of SQL server image data type ,
here is my code :

```
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select id_image1 from work_tbl where 
    work_id =  12345 ", conn)
    Dim stream As New MemoryStream()
    conn.Open()
    Dim image As Byte() = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())
    stream.Write(image, 0, image.Length)
    conn.Close()
    Dim bitmap As New Bitmap(stream)
    picturebox1.Image = bitmap
```

I need to stop the procedure with msgbox if my image column is **empty** .

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select id_image1 from work_tbl where 
work_id =  12345 ", conn)
Dim stream As New MemoryStream()
conn.Open()
```

if DBNull(cmd.ExecuteScalar())=false

```
Dim image As Byte() = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())
stream.Write(image, 0, image.Length)
Dim bitmap As New Bitmap(stream)
picturebox1.Image = bitmap
```

end if 
conn.Close()